# elasticsearch-curator installation error "cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named vcruntime140.dll"

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip, pypi, elasticsearch-curator

The following error occurred while installing `elasticsearch-curator`

```
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named vcruntime140.dll
```

Here is command I did

```
pip install -U elasticsearch-curator
```

The last error message is below

```
  copying curator\validators\__init__.py -> build\lib\curator\validators
  copying curator\validators\actions.py -> build\lib\curator\validators
  copying curator\validators\config_file.py -> build\lib\curator\validators
  copying curator\validators\filters.py -> build\lib\curator\validators
  copying curator\validators\options.py -> build\lib\curator\validators
  copying curator\validators\schemacheck.py -> build\lib\curator\validators
  running build_exe
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8urft708\elasticsearch-curator\setup.py", line 140, in <module>
      executables = [curator_exe,curator_cli_exe,repomgr_exe]
    File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 340, in setup
      distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\python\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 210, in run
      zipExcludePackages = self.zip_exclude_packages)
    File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 105, in __init__
      self._VerifyConfiguration()
    File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 460, in _VerifyConfiguration
      sourceFileName)
  cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named vcruntime140.dll
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for elasticsearch-curator
```

OS : Windows 10
Python Version : 3.7.4

How can I install?

Comment: This question might be better on the [elastic/curator issue tracker](https://github.com/elastic/curator/issues)

Comment: @DustinIngram ok i will do it

Answer (score 0):

You would typically find that DLL by downloading and installing the "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio".